# Run a task in background and continue execution

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have a long running library method (3rd party) that returns a System.Threading.Tasks.Task. How can I tell it to run in background and continue my code execution? I'd also like to get a callback once it finishes successfully or with an exception.

Comment: Are you saying that the method runs on the current thread and then returns a completed `Task`? That would be quite weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it returns a `Task`, then it almost certainly *does* run in the background. An instance of `Task` represents the completion status of something that's running asynchronously; that's what the `Task` class is for.

And the `Task` gives you the opportunity to request a callback. Just call `.ContinueWith(your callback)`.

There are several overloads of `ContinueWith` that let you specify options if you wish, like "only call my callback if the task completed successfully" or "only call my callback if the task failed with an exception".